# Delphi XE: How to add the current date into the build directory name

Tags: delphi, build

When I push the "Release"-Button I want that Delphi XE automatically create a new directory like "C:\MyProject\2015-01-21\", "C:\MyProject\2015-01-22\" and so on

If and how is it possible to dynamically add the current date to the release directory?

Comment: You can specify these directory using environment variables. So you would want to arrange for your process to run with an environment block that contained the current date. Easy enough to do with a plugin.

Comment: Or maybe use a [Pre-Build event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Build_Events) to run a script that sets those variables and creates the folder.

Comment: @Remy Pre build script runs in a child process. Won't be able to change the environment of parent.